# jQuery :: How to execute one function based off two possible events

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking for a clean way to fire one function that may be triggered by two possible events. For example:

```
$('form').on('submit', function() {
    stuff in here...
});

$('input').on('change', function() {
    same stuff in here as before...
});
```

I could do

```
function doStuff() {
    Stuff in here....
}

$('form').on('submit', function() {
    doStuff();
});

$('input').on('change', function() {
    doStuff();
});
```

But I was wondering if there was a more elegant way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function doStuff() {
    Stuff in here....
}

$('form').on('submit', doStuff);

$('input').on('change', doStuff);
```

Comment: OK, I guess that slims it up a bit.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {

    $('form').submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        stuff('aaa');
        $(this).unbind().submit();
    });

    $('input').change(function() {
        stuff('aaa');
    });
});

function stuff(param){
    // Some Processing!
    return(param);
}
```